# Unable to download a PDF file - browser keep loading

Tags: pdf, download

For some reasons, some of the PDF files on my website is unable to download through the browser.  When I copy the full path to the file on the Server and paste to the browser, the browser keep loading forever.  There's no error on the Server log / Apache log / PHP log

This problem is only happen to some of the PDF files, some of them are fine - I just click and download straightaway.

I also take the problem PDF files and upload to a different Server, and the same problem again.

I'm now thinking about the problem is something inside the PDF file but not the Server.

I did check the PDF file and see if there's any security that caused the problem but there's no security at all.

Did you guys ever come across a problem like this before?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem was caused by our network, when I access from an outside network, I can download all PDF files without any issue.